# Sweet Alert error, Class'UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlertServiceProvider'

Tags: laravel

i have installed the sweet alert package into my laravel 5.0 application but i keep getting this error => Class'UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlertServiceProvider' not found

Comment: Did you install `SweetAlert` with composer? If not, then you will need to update your composer.json to tell it where to point the autoloader for that class.

Comment: yeah in composer.json i included this in the required like so....
"require": {
   "uxweb/sweet-alert":"~1.1"
}

and added the providers and the aliases. 
and even run a composer update. but still gives me that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing this line:

**UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlertServiceProvider::class**

Add above line at the **config/app.php** file. There you would find **provider**. It should be added there.
Hence Your Provider would look like this then:

App\Providers\EventServiceProvider::class,        App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider::class,
UxWeb\SweetAlert\SweetAlertServiceProvider::class,

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

After that you have to specify the provider in which ever controller file you are using it in.
Like we specify model in controllers before using it:

**use App\Providers\SweetAlertServiceProvider;**

**above your class** in your controller file

Comment: am using windows so i used CMD. Anyway thanks i have been able to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a new class to your project it won't load unless it's included in autoload_classmap.

In your termainal, navigate to the app folder and run `composer dump-autoload`.

Comment: Can anyone send me a link to a site where i can get video tutorial on how to use jquery ajax in Laravel for free apart from YouTube.